# Track and find assembly file from AssemblyInfo.CS

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a source code collection for a web application. Under one of the 'Properties' folder - I have an AssemblyInfo.CS.

While I understand this defines and describes an assembly nearby, how can I target and find out this assembly file? (Not sure what I'm looking for)

Reason: The Assembly Info talks about a copyrighted assembly and I need to find out which files are copyrighted.

Comment: Everything in that project is part of that assembly.

Comment: That's what I figured, thanks @Amy appreciate your response. Why not put this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in that project is part of that assembly unless its 'Build Action' is set to 'None' or 'Content'.  You can generally expect everything in the project will be 'Compile', or 'Embedded Resource', and so will be part of the assembly.